Copying text marked as text-decoration: underline will paste as underlined
I have a weird issue in app that I am building:
I have a part where text gets displayed, and certain words get tagged with a span which has a class of annotation. This annotation has a text-decoration: underline style, nothing fancy.
If I now paste this text into either a div with content-editable=true or a program like MS Office Word, the text that has the annotation class is actually being converted into something that resembles being underlined in full.
I tried the same in Firefox, and it did not behave the same - though all Chromium browser did.
Example:

gets pasted into a rich-text field (which highlights the word again, internally) as:

same with Word:

I looked at what Chrome puts into the clipboard, and here is what's added as text/html:
<span style="color: rgb(68, 64, 60); font-family: InterVariable, Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">were once<span>&nbsp;</span></span><span class="annotation " style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 0px solid rgb(228, 228, 231); --tw-border-spacing-x: 0; --tw-border-spacing-y: 0; --tw-translate-x: 0; --tw-translate-y: 0; --tw-rotate: 0; --tw-skew-x: 0; --tw-skew-y: 0; --tw-scale-x: 1; --tw-scale-y: 1; --tw-pan-x: ; --tw-pan-y: ; --tw-pinch-zoom: ; --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity; --tw-gradient-from-position: ; --tw-gradient-via-position: ; --tw-gradient-to-position: ; --tw-ordinal: ; --tw-slashed-zero: ; --tw-numeric-figure: ; --tw-numeric-spacing: ; --tw-numeric-fraction: ; --tw-ring-inset: ; --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px; --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff; --tw-ring-color: #fde04766; --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset)0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width)var(--tw-ring-offset-color); --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset)0 0 0 calc(2px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width))var(--tw-ring-color); --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000; --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000; --tw-blur: ; --tw-brightness: ; --tw-contrast: ; --tw-grayscale: ; --tw-hue-rotate: ; --tw-invert: ; --tw-saturate: ; --tw-sepia: ; --tw-drop-shadow: ; --tw-backdrop-blur: ; --tw-backdrop-brightness: ; --tw-backdrop-contrast: ; --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ; --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ; --tw-backdrop-invert: ; --tw-backdrop-opacity: ; --tw-backdrop-saturate: ; --tw-backdrop-sepia: ; --tw-contain-size: ; --tw-contain-layout: ; --tw-contain-paint: ; --tw-contain-style: ; cursor: pointer; text-underline-offset: 3px; border-radius: 0.25rem; text-decoration: underline; background-color: rgba(253, 224, 71, 0.4); box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow),var(--tw-ring-shadow),var(--tw-shadow,0 0 #0000); color: rgb(68, 64, 60); font-family: InterVariable, Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal;">Olympic swimming</span><span style="color: rgb(68, 64, 60); font-family: InterVariable, Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;"><span>&nbsp;</span>rivals,</span>

here is what Firefox puts into the clipboard:
were once <span class="annotation">Olympic swimming</span> rivals

which is pretty much how the original HTML looked like.
Is there a way to not have the styling be copied into the clipboard as well? Or at least change it so the underline style is not picked up?
I noticed that Chrome adds extra styles when copy html to clipboard could be a related question
I already tried changing the text-decoration to something using border-bottom, however that breaks other styling in my app and can't be used, same with a combination that uses an ::after tag.

Thanks for the link, however I don't want to remove all styling or replace the HTML with raw text. I actually like that it can copy the styled text (italics, bold, ...), I just would like the underlining to stop. I have been thinking about a CSS solution to change the way the annotations work...

I guess one approach could be to use the answer from that question, but instead of just setting the HTML to plain text, you get the JS to just remove text-decoration: underline from the HTML that gets sent to the clipboard. Otherwise, maybe border-bottom in CSS doesn't get copied across?

thanks for the tip with border-bottom, but I already tried that and it breaks the styling across the app where the class is used as well. I will see if there is a way to overwrite it using JS, even though that sounds like i need more clipboard permissions... and might not work on all platforms. having a "native" function to control this would be best :/

Whenever some text is copied to the clipboard, we can prevent the default behaviour and implement the copy functionality ourselves instead. For instance, we could get the selected text, clone it somewhere, update the styles as we desire, and then copy that HTML to the clipboard, using the basic approach from this question.


document.addEventListener("copy", (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
  recursivelyUpdateStyles(selection);
  
  const result = document.createElement("div");
  result.append(selection);
  
  event.preventDefault();
  event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", result.innerHTML);
});

function recursivelyUpdateStyles(node) {
  for (const child of node.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) continue;

    child.style.textDecoration = "none";
    recursivelyUpdateStyles(child);
  }
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.red {
  color: #f00;
}
Some text <span class="underline">with underline</span> and <span class="red">formatting</span> to copy.
<br><br>
<div contenteditable="true">Try pasting here</div>



